# confused how to go about using \= when updating a knowledge base

Tags: prolog

Swi-prolog syntax questions; I'm pretty confused how to go about using \= when updating a knowledge base. I'm writing a predicate where I want to print out all the songs karen can perform to except heyJude.

```
canPerform(karen, Song) :-
   song(Song =\= heyJude).
```

Is this accurate?

Answer (score 0):

Prolog is **not** a functional programming language. You likely want:

```
canPerform(karen, Song) :- song(Song), Song \== heyJude.
```

Also, Prolog coding style guides usually dictate CamelCase only for variables. Thus I suggest you rename your atoms to:

```
can_perform(karen, Song) :- song(Song), Song \== hey_jude.
```

Comment: `(=\=)/2` produces a `type_error(evaluable, heyJude)`, rather use `dif/2` instead.